# Simple Scorecard Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-arrayformula

I simply want to create a scoresheet comparing scores to par.  If less than par then a red number, if more than par then highlight red, if equal to par then highlight green.  Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

Par = cell B5 thru J5 and L5 thru T5
Score = if B6 thru J6 and L6 thru T6 are lower than par, the number is red; if equal to par then highlight green; if greater than par then highlight red.

I've tried it numerous times and it doesn't work.  Can someone assist, please?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

#### red color:

```
=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B5:T6),
 IF(B5:T5 > B6:T6, 2,
 IF(B5:T5 < B6:T6, 2, )), ))=2, 1)
```

#### green color:

```
=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B$5:T6),
 IF(B$5:T$5 = B$6:T$6, 1, ), ))=1, 1)
```

[image: 0]